# Claimed to be the same height but doesn't seem to be

Tags: html, css, header, height

[Difference between the headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I18yU.png)

[The website's header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuevB.png)

[My header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0iPF.png)

Can anyone please tell me what is the thing that is probably making this happen?

[This is my span's style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDD8J.png)

[This is the website's span's style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROlIk.png)

Edit: I tried to make the headers of stack overflow and facebook, I did not have the same problem, but I need to know why this website is like this.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is the same, but the page is just resized. If both browser windows were the same size, they would be the same. The difference is very slight anyway.

Comment: No, there are not the same and my boss telling me to do the design exactly the same as that website.

Comment: The whole time the two windows were zoomed in at different rates lol, sorry for that.

Comment: It's ok. The most important thing is that we learn from our mistakes.